# Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable (Can´t run a python program using Spark)

Tags: python, java, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using built-in-java classes where applicable (Can´t run a python program using Spark). I am trying to run this code just for testing if sparks work:

### Code

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName('sparkdf').getOrCreate()
data = [["node.js", "dbms", "integration"],
        ["jsp", "SQL", "trigonometry"],
        ["php", "oracle", "statistics"],
        [".net", "db2", "Machine Learning"]]
columns = ["Web Technologies", "Data bases", "Maths"]
dataframe = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)
dataframe.show()
```

I think enviroment variables are set up correctly and  winutils.exe is located at the Hadoop\bin directory. But i kept getting this error:

### Error

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
22/04/26 12:48:44 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ldocampo\prueba.py", line 10, in <module>
    spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName('sparkdf').getOrCreate()
  File "C:\Users\ldocampo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\session.py", line 228, in getOrCreate
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
  File "C:\Users\ldocampo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py", line 384, in getOrCreate
    SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
  File "C:\Users\ldocampo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py", line 146, in __init__
    self._do_init(master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer,
  File "C:\Users\ldocampo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py", line 209, in _do_init
    self._jsc = jsc or self._initialize_context(self._conf._jconf)
  File "C:\Users\ldocampo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py", line 321, in _initialize_context
    return self._jvm.JavaSparkContext(jconf)
  File "C:\Users\ldocampo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1568, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
  File "C:\Users\ldocampo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
    raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$ (in unnamed module @0x51f116b8) cannot access class sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.nio.ch to unnamed module @0x51f116b8
        at org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$.<init>(StorageUtils.scala:213)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$.<clinit>(StorageUtils.scala)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.<init>(BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.scala:110)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.$anonfun$create$9(SparkEnv.scala:348)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.registerOrLookupEndpoint$1(SparkEnv.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:336)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:191)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:277)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:460)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:67)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:483)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
        at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
        at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Comment: Your actual error is `java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$ (in unnamed module @0x51f116b8) cannot access class sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer`. Please ensure you're using Java 11

Comment: Thank you for the help. I am using Java 18.

Comment: Read the Spark documentation carefully around the installation sections. Java 18 is not supported